# How to use calloc?

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, tcp, calloc

Note : Function to receive **"data"** at the **server** from a **client**

**Client Code**

```
void send_file(FILE *fp, int sockfd){

    int size;
    char *buffer;

    while ((fp = fopen("/home/regs_p/cprograms/crypt/RSA.c","r")) != NULL){

        if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("Error opening the file : RSA.c\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        size = ftell(fp);
        rewind (fp);

        // Allocate a buffer to contain all characters of the file

        buffer = calloc(1, sizeof (char) * (size + 1));

        if (buffer == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Sorry, space is insufficient!");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        fread(buffer, size, 1, fp);

        printf("File size = %d\n", size);
        write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));

        free(buffer);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    close(sockfd);
    return;
}
```

**Server Code**

```
void recv_file(int sockfd){
        
    char *buffer;
    buffer = calloc(1, sizeof (char) * (strlen(sockfd));

    if (buffer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Sorry, but you can not insert more articles, the space is insufficient\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
         
    printf("Length of the file received has %d characters!", strlen(buffer));
```

[image: Screenshot of the Error]

Comment: Do not paste text as images. Copy and paste it as text. You can enclose it in `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags to mark it as “preformatted text” to preserve the spacing and line endings.

Comment: `strlen(sockfd)` is terribly, horribly wrong if `sockfd` is meant to be a socket file descriptor as its name suggests.  I suppose that you're trying to determine how much data there is to read, but you simply cannot do that without actually reading it.  `strlen()` is for determining the length of a valid C string that is already resident in memory, and its argument must be a pointer to the first character of that string.

Comment: The problem isn't `calloc`, the problem is `strlen(sockfd)`. What is the length of a number?

Comment: The messages do not match the posted source code. The posted source code has `(strlen(sockfd))`, but the messages show `((int *) strlen(sockfd)) + 1)`. Always match the source code and error messages exactly; do not use messages from a different version of the source code than posted. Differences can affect diagnosis.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - Yes. I know that, 'sockfd' is a socket file descriptor.  I'm trying to determine the size of the data, create a file and store the data there.

Comment: As the message “passing argument 1 of ’strlen’ makes a pointer from integer” states, `sockfd` is an integer; it is simply an **integer** to indicate one of the files/streams your process has open. `strlen` is a function that counts the length of a string; it must be given a **pointer** to the first character of the string. For example, if `sockfd` is 5 because it is stream number 5 for your process, `strlen(sockfd)` asks “What is the length of the string 5?” But 5 is not a string. It is not clear to us what length you are attempting to calculate here.

Comment: Further, `strlen` returns an integer number of characters. Your code, as shown in the error messages, has a cast, `(int *)`, which attempts to convert it to a pointer. There is no reason to do that, and it makes no sense. The return value of `strlen` is something like 13, for 13 characters. An address is a place in memory. You do not change lengths of strings into addresses in memory.

Comment: What do you want to allocate space for? How much do you think you need to allocate? Why? What does the socket have to do with it? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Ace.McCloud, it seems like you would benefit from a general tutorial on working with sockets and low-level POSIX I/O functions.  Although we answer questions on those topics, and you can find plenty of example code here, we do not do tutorials.  I suggest looking up a coherent, comprehensive treatment of the topic elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - how to determine, amount of data send from the client at the server?

Comment: The loop condition and the `if` check inside the loop doesn't make any sense together. Inside the loop `fp` will *never* be a null pointer.

Comment: As for the amount of data to send, you already have it in the `size` variable.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - I have added client code. Using, write() at the client -> I'm trying to determine 'strlen(buffer)' at the server

Comment: There's a problem with the communication protocol as well: How would the server know how much data to receive? You need to invent an actual *protocol* for the communication. For example you could send the `size` first (as a fixed four-byte `int` value in a specified byte-order) followed by the actual data. Then the server would first read the size, and then read the data.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Yes. That makes sense. I've to send the file 'size' first and then read the data. Thanks!

Comment: @Ace.McCloud You don't have to. You could have a protocol that says that all and only what's sent is the file and the receiver can determine the end because the socket will be closed. This is what the earliest versions of the HTTP protocol did.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz -  I dont want to close the socket as soon as I read the file size. How about use, sleep() and keep the socket open at the server (all the time) so as to receive data from the client using write()? Is this a good idea?

Comment: @Ace.McCloud No. If you want to wait for data, wait for data by blocking in `read` or `recv`.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

- DO NOT LINK TO PICTURES OF CODE OR ERRORS.  Cut and paste the errors into the body of your question, along with the source code.
- `strlen` expects its argument to have type `char *` and to be a *pointer to the first character of a zero-terminated string*.  `sockfd` is neither of these things.  Casting it from `int` to a pointer type doesn't fix anything because it's not a pointer *value*.
- `strlen` returns a value of type `size_t`, not `int`, so you need to use the `%zu` conversion specifier instead of `%d` to print it.

The length of your error buffer will need to be determined by something other than  the socket file descriptor.  You'll need to pass a second parameter to your `recv_file` function:

```
void recv_file( int sockfd, size_t bufsize )
{
  char *buffer = calloc( bufsize+1, sizeof *buffer );
  if ( !buffer )
    ...
}
```

or you'll need to rely on a constant:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 128 // or however long it needs to be
...
void recv_file( int sockfd )
{
  char *buffer = calloc( BUFFER_SIZE+1, sizeof *buffer );
  if ( !buffer )
    ...
}
```

at which point you might as well make `buffer` a regular array:

```
void recv_file( int sockfd )
{
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE+1] = {0};
  ...
}
```

and avoid memory management headaches altogether.

Answer (score 0):

And you cannot tell how long the file is either just by looking at the tcp connection. You will have to send the length first and then the data. You will need to keep looping on the receive.

This because tcp is a stream protocol. The only guarantee is that the byes you send arrive in the same order. But you could do 1 send of 50 bytes and receive 50 1 byte message